# How to Modify this NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary which contain this data:

```
    (
contact={name="Lion",id="1",photo="simba.png",address="elm street"},
    {name="Cat",id="2",photo="halleberry.png",address="attic"},
    {name="Bat",id="3",photo="dracule.jpg",address="long way home baby"}
    )
```

From that NSDictionary, i grab only the name and sorted it alphabetically. Like this:

```
(B={"Bat"}, C={"Cat"}, L={"Lion"})
```

This is the code i used:

```
NSMutableDictionary* sortedDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 for (NSDictionary* animal in dataDict[@"user"]){
    NSString* name = animal[@"name"];
    if (![name length])
       continue;
     NSRange range = [name rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:0];
     NSString* key = [[name substringWithRange:range] uppercaseString];
     NSMutableArray* list = sortedDict[key];
     if (!list){
        list = [NSMutableArray array];
        [sortedDict setObject:list forKey:key];
     }
     [list addObject:name];
```

Then, what i want to ask is. What i need to create an array of photos but sorted alphabetically based on the name. I mean something like this:

```
(B="dracule.jpg", C="halleberry.png"...etc)
```

I also heard that this will be more effective to use `(B={name="Bat", photo="draggle.jpg"})` but don't know how i can make something like this and don't know how to call it separately. Please i need your help :"(

Comment: I don't understand the data you present.  It starts with `(`, which implies an array, and yet has a key of `contact` with a value of a dictionary but then there are more dictionaries following that.  Please describe your data better.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i made some mistake because i type it not copy and paste but both are NSDictionary

Comment: So where are the keys for the 2nd and 3rd element of the top-level dictionary?

Comment: name, id, photo, address is all key

Comment: OK nevermind, I don't seem to be able to get through to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily sort the array which contains dictionaries values, see below

```
//Get the contact array.

NSArray *contacts=[dic objectForKey:@"contact"];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortedArray = [contacts sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: If i make it like this, it only sorted the names, but i also need the initial to make an index @iphonic

Comment: @Edward Do you want indexing of the sorted data, or just indexing, or indexing first then sort indexed data ?

Comment: indexing first then sort the data. I want to make something like [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/)